# translate gray image with emgu cv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am working on an Emgucv project and I have stuck at a point. I want to change the normal picture to gray picture. But I didn't. 
first, how will I do it?
and finally, I installed to change with `ımage<>[]`  array to `ımage<>` and string error

thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to add references and dll files on your project. Make sure you have added assembly reference to your class file

```
Emgu.CV.Structure;

Emgu.CV;
```

Then this is only what you need to do,

```
Image<Gray, byte> imggray = inputImg.Convert<Gray, byte>();
```